# ASP.NET BoundColumn ToolTip

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, tooltip, boundcolumn

Is there a way to add a tool tip to a BoundColumn? This is my code....

```
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PersonName" SortExpression="PersonName" HeaderText="Name">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" VerticalAlign="Top"></HeaderStyle>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundColumn>
```

I was using a tablecell before and decided to switch to a bound column, in doing so I realized tooltips are not an attribute of boundcolumn, I need tooltips.

Comment: You want the same tooltip for every row's cell in that column, even the header and footer?

Comment: No, I have 10 different columns all with different tooltips, before I was placing the tooltip on the header of the column. I would like to do the same.

Comment: every row's cell that belongs to these columns should have this tooltip or only the header?

Comment: Only the header. If I have a column called Name, I want to be able to scroll over the column header and see the tooltip. I do not need it for  every cell in the column.

Comment: Is this a `GridView`?

Comment: So a `DataGrid` or a control inheriting from `DataGrid` or from `GridView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's actually a `DataGrid` control and you want to have a tooltip on the header-cell. You can use `ItemDataBound`:

```
Protected Sub SortableDataGrid_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles Grid0.RowDataBound
    Select Case e.Item.ItemType
        Case ListItemType.Header
            'presuming it's the first column:
            e.Item.Cells(0).ToolTip = "Your tooltip for this header cell"
    End Select
End Sub
```

If it's a `GridView` the code is similar:

```
Protected Sub SortableGridView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Grid0.RowDataBound
    Select Case e.Row.RowType
        Case DataControlRowType.Header
            'presuming it's the first column:
            e.Row.Cells(0).ToolTip = "Your tooltip for this header cell"
    End Select
End Sub
```